# Wordpress and Jquery scrollTop

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Can anyone tell me why this code isn't working on a Wordpress website?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avqLkd33/6/)

```
('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#descricao-credito-pessoal').offset().top}, 1000);
```

I've searched and saw answers that assigning overflow to html element may prevent it from working, and it had overflow hidden. I removed but the problem stays the same.
It's odd because it was working before.

The behaviour is that when the link div is clicked, it scrolls down like around 5 pixels (without animation). The div where it should scroll to is not in view so it should scroll much more...

I'm using latest stable release of Jquery.

html is already there, there is no html beeing inserted with jquery.
There are no console errors.

If anyone has a thought please share.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I had a plugin installed (Jquery Updater) which was placing Jquery to latest stable build (3.3 i assume).

Defining 3.0 didn't work.

Defining 3.1 and jquery migrate to gitbuild solved the problem.

*Thank you to the one that voted down my topic. I didn't want people to solve the problem for me, i like to solve problems on my own, just wanted to know for opinions.